# Get rid of DC offset by subtracting mean, but still have impulse at f = 0 Hz

Tags: matlab, highpass-filter

I understand that there are two ways to get rid of DC offset: (1) subtracting mean of original signal in time-domain, (2) using high-pass filter. I'm trying both approaches on my data (using Matlab) but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

[image]

The plot in (2.1) is obtained by doing `new_signal = orig_signal - mean(orig_signal)`. The plot in (2.2) is obtained by doing `new_signal = highpass(orig_signal, 0.08)`.

- Am I correctly removing DC offset from my original signal?
- Is it ok that the plots (2.1) and (2.2) look different?
- Any suggestions for removing DC offset in Matlab? Suggestions using Python would help as well.

Comment: Hi, I agree with Tim, and the spectrum you call 'AFTER removing mean' is quite the same, if not exactly the same, as the one before attempting DC removal. Even the spectrum claiming DC filtered, still has strong DC, doesn't it? Any chance readers have a look at the MATLAB code or Simulink diagram of the circuit you have used in both attempts?

Answer (score 6):

Take a close look at the spectrum of your signal minus the mean -- you should see that the bin at f = 0 is actually zero.

But your original signal has a strong slope to it.  When you take the FFT of this signal, it is going to have strong content *around* f = 0, even if the f = 0 bin itself is zeroed out.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you probably want to *detrend* the data (with a function named `detrend`).  Then you want to *window* the data with an appropriate window.  Doing both of those together should get you reasonable results.

Comment: The function you're mentioning is [detrend](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/detrend.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I know that's what it's named in Scilab, but I haven't used Matlab for decades.

Answer (score 1):

**1.-** The way to remove signal DC is with **series capacitance**.

Many Spectrum Analyzers, desktop/rack instruments, include **internal DC block**.

However, additionally using a **DC block** right on the input port may save the instrument.

**1.1.-** [Example hardware](https://www.fairviewmicrowave.com/n-dc-blocks-category.aspx?keyword=dc%20blocks&msclkid=f8aebd58d2ac1b357b8ededb87c6be43&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Search%20DSA%20%7C%20DC%20Blocks&utm_term=dc%20blocks&utm_content=DC%20Blocks) **10MHz to 18GHz** N-type 1dB Insertion Loss, standing up to 200V (Vdc ? Vac ?) at $238.99/unit (min order quantity 13 !)

**1.2.-** A cheap (AU$29.22) 2W **DC to 8GHz** (20dB) here:

https://www.cseonline.com.au/KARN-50-TERMINATION-N-Type.html

datasheet : https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/KARN-50+.pdf

Some really good *'RF microwave DC blocks'* do not perform that well below certain frequency.

So it's good practice to use a **tested hardware** DC blocks that make sure **no DC gets in instruments**, particularly the expensive ones.

**1.3.-** [The compromise](https://www.amazon.co.uk/female-DC-BLOCK-block-coaxial-connector-2W-N-JK/dp/B07ZF9M84T/ref=asc_df_B07ZF9M84T?tag=bingshoppinga-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=80470608884499&hvnetw=o&hvqmt=e&hvbmt=be&hvdev=c&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=&hvtargid=pla-4584070151964776&psc=1) £13.73 **DC to 3GHz**

**2.-** The image of the signal supplied in the question is mostly contained below 100Hz, all the above spectrum at -60dB (-90dBm) is **nothing but noise** ; system, channel, or who knows what.

The shoulder between 6kHz and 8kHz **is not signal**.

[image]

Found 2 **Simulink** examples using DC blocks [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ug/dc-blocker-with-fixed-point-data.html?s_tid=srchtitle_spectrum%2520analyzer%2520dc%2520blocker_9) :

[image]

and [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ug/use-dc-blocker-to-remove-dc-component-of-signal.html?s_tid=srchtitle_spectrum%2520analyzer%2520dc%2520blocker_10)

[image]

**3.-** **Simulating signal** in the question :

Please comment accordingly if it turns out that the simulated signal requires modification.

```
dt=.01;
t=[0:dt:50];
x=linspace(-917.5,914.5,numel(t))+.9*randi([-100 100],1,numel(t));

figure
plot(t,x)
grid on
xlabel('t');ylabel('x(t)')
```

[image]

```
% SA
NAvg = 100;
Fs = 1e7;
FrameSize = 64;
NumFreqBins = 2048;
filterBankRBW = Fs/NumFreqBins;

SA = dsp.SpectrumAnalyzer(...
    'ChannelNames',{'ch1'}, ...
    'Method','Filter bank',...
    'NumTapsPerBand',24,...
    'SampleRate',Fs,...
    'RBWSource','Property',...
    'RBW',filterBankRBW,...
    'SpectralAverages',NAvg,...
    'PlotAsTwoSidedSpectrum',false,...
    'YLimits',[-150 50],...
    'YLabel','Power',...
    'Title','Filter bank PSD',...
    'Position',[50 375 800 450]);

noiseVar = 1e-12;
noiseFloor = 10*log10((noiseVar/(NumFreqBins/2))/1e-3); % -114 dBm onesided
fprintf('Noise Floor\n');
fprintf('Filter bank noise floor = %.2f dBm\n\n',noiseFloor);

timesteps = 10 * ceil(NumFreqBins / FrameSize);
for t = 1:timesteps
%     x = sum(sinegen(),2) + sqrt(noiseVar)*randn(FrameSize,1);
    SA(x');
end

release(SA)
```

**Power Spectrum Density** of signal

[image]

**4.-** Using the following **Simulink circuit** one can see that the **DC block** actually removes DC but it's really close to 0Hz and only when there's relevant DC bias.

[image]

zoomed around 0Hz

[image]

**A DC block is not going to actively bring noise below the system level**, as I understand was expected by the question originator, let me explain :

note that **3 DC blocks** bring down DC around **18dB**.

These are **Power Spectral Density** figures `dBmW/Hz` .

**5.-** **Open the Simulink DC block** : there's an option to check how it is built

[image]

The **DC block** is actually a **passive filter** implemented with **IIR**. The zoomed response around 0Hz of this DC block is

[image]

**6.-** Now with a **single Simulink DC block** only attenuates **20dB on DC**

[image]

[image]

So

**6.1.-** Serially adding DC blocks **does not add** attenuation **linearly**

**6.2.-** Now DC is brought down nearly 20dB : **a single DC is more efficient blocking DC**, and

**6.3.-** **A single DC block adds less noise** onto the input signal than 3 using 3 series **DC blocks**.

**Friis noise formula** for series chain applies.

**Passive devices cannot bring signals below the system / room / channel they operate on.**

**7.- MATLAB Simulink Spectrum built-in Analyzer SA configuration** explained [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/spectrumanalyzer.html?s_tid=srchtitle_spectrum%2520analyzer%2520dc%2520block_1)

Thanks for reading.